# I Can't Change Album Art On Three Songs By One Artist

Tags: samsung

I tried everything, even reformatting the phone. I never had this problem before.
The album art shows up properly on my computer.

New: I copied the songs from another phone, each song had the same profile pictures like it should, but it was still in two albums like before. When I moved the files from phone storage to the SD card via phone, the 3 songs went back to black album art and and it is still in two albums.

Comment: Try using Mixplorer (download free from XDA to add album art. [FAQ of Mixplorer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/mixplorer-q-a-and-faq-user-manual.3308582/)